# JPA EclipseLink with @TableGenerator. Why is the value assigned to id not null after transaction rollback?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, eclipselink

I have the following entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "sales", schema = "cust_tables")
@Multitenant(MultitenantType.TABLE_PER_TENANT)
@TenantTableDiscriminator(contextProperty = "customer_schema", type = TenantTableDiscriminatorType.SCHEMA)
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class Sale implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "Sale")
    @TableGenerator(name = "Sale", schema = "thehub", allocationSize = 5)
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @XmlElement
    private Long id;
```

During a persist operation, I may intentionally allow the transaction to rollback during an optimistic locking failure.

I'm surprised by the behavior of JPA/EclipseLink during this scenario however. JPA assigns a value from the sequence to `id`, as expected. However, during the rollback, this value is not 'blanked out'. Then next time I try to persist, a value for `id` is already there. JPA Skips pulling a new number from the sequence and attempts to persist the entity.

I'm failing with a SQL integrity constraint exception:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.0.v20130226-e0971b1): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Duplicate entry '51' for key 'PRIMARY'
Error Code: 1062
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When a JPA transaction fails, all of the object become detached.  You cannot re-submit the transaction.

You need to create a new persistence context, and either need to recreate the objects, or if you want to use the existing ones carefully merge then into the new persistence context and null out their ids.  Also, for any objects updated you will need to revert their version fields.

JPA does not offer an easy way to resubmit a transaction.  EclipseLink's native API offers commitAndResumeOnFailure(), but this is not exposed to JPA.  Perhaps log an enhancement requests to have some sort of option to allow resubmitting failed transaction in JPA.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, though resubmitting the transaction wasn't the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I managed to figure this out, and I will post my results here to help anyone that may encounter the same problem.

Using a debugger I can see EclipseLink does indeed assign a value to the entity.id field, even during a transaction rollback. If you're like me, your id fields are annotated and your ID is immutable, meaning there is only a getter and not a setter. EclipseLink is capable of using reflection to assign a value to the field, but your API that is exposed prevents mutation of the id field. (This is a 'good thing').

EclipseLink appears to, either by design or by bug, to assign a value to the ID field and remove that value from the ID sequence. So a transaction rollback will cause a hole in your sequence numbers(which isn't really that big of a crime).

Keep in mind, EclipseLink reads the sequence number table, caches up a few sequence numbers in memory, then re-reads it when it's cache is empty, while committing a starting value for the next sequence.

Somehow, through a combination of transaction rollbacks and restarting my server, the sequence number table fell behind the actual sequence number being used. So the bug is not assigning an ID during a transaction rollback, the bug is losing track of the sequence number. What I ended up with was the sequence number table have a value of 50, but the highest numbered entity in my database was 51. The solution was to update the sequence table to twice the allocationSize(5), setting it to 60, and bounce my server.

Unfortunately, I'm not able to reproduce this bug. :( I have no idea how EclipseLink got into the malformed state.

Comment: It might be a different bug, but I had similar problems with EclipseLink when doing a `DROP_AND_CREATE` which was somehow not dropping everything and complaining that the entities already existed.  I had to drop the schema directly from SQL.

Comment: EclipseLink will normally allocate sequence numbers outside of the transaction context, so allocated ids will never be reassigned.  However, if you use JTA or trigger a flush() then the sequence allocation will use the current transaction.  This is bad, and the solution is to use a sequence connection pool. See, http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/jpa/extensions/p_connection_pool_sequence.htm#BABIDAGH

Comment: the documentation there isn't very good, could you explain a bit more about this in an answer? I do have a flush() in the code to force a check for some unique keys